# I am getting Class Not Found Exception while starting Android application. can any one tell me the cause?

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am new to android application and i am getting `classNotFound exception` while running android application.

i pasted logcat,manifest file and java code.

can anyone know the cause of the problem?

**LogCat:-**

```
02-25 12:10:20.071: W/dalvikvm(273): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/phonegap/plugins/downloader/MainActivity; (35)
02-25 12:10:20.071: W/dalvikvm(273): Link of class 'Lcom/phonegap/plugins/downloader/MainActivity;' failed
02-25 12:10:20.071: D/AndroidRuntime(273): Shutting down VM
02-25 12:10:20.071: W/dalvikvm(273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.phonegap.plugins.downloader/com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.phonegap.plugins.downloader-1.apk]
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.phonegap.plugins.downloader-1.apk]
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-25 12:10:20.101: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

**JavaCode:-**

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.downloader;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/download/download.html");
    }

}
```

**Manifest File:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.plugins.downloader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.Downloader" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Downloader.java**

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.downloader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Environment;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class Downloader extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {

        if (!action.equals("downloadFile")) 
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);

        try {

            String fileUrl = args.getString(0);
            JSONObject params = args.getJSONObject(1);

            String fileName = params.has("fileName") ? 
                    params.getString("fileName"):
                    fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

            String dirName = params.has("dirName") ?
                    params.getString("dirName"):
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/download";

            Boolean overwrite = params.has("overwrite") ? params.getBoolean("overwrite") : false;

            return this.downloadUrl(fileUrl, dirName, fileName, overwrite, callbackId);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private PluginResult downloadUrl(String fileUrl, String dirName, String fileName, Boolean overwrite, String callbackId) throws InterruptedException, JSONException {

        try {

            Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "Downloading "+fileUrl + " into " + dirName + "/" + fileName);

            File dir = new File(dirName);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "directory " + dirName + " created");
                dir.mkdirs();
            }

            File file = new File(dirName, fileName);

            if (!overwrite && file.exists()) {
                Log.d("DownloaderPlugin", "File already exist");

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("status", 1);
                obj.put("total", 0);
                obj.put("file", fileName);
                obj.put("dir", dirName);
                obj.put("progress", 100);

                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj);
            }

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            ucon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            ucon.connect();

            Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "Download start");

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int readed = 0, 
                progress = 0,
                totalReaded = 0,
                fileSize = ucon.getContentLength();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            while ((readed = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                fos.write(buffer, 0, readed);
                totalReaded += readed;

                int newProgress = (totalReaded*100/fileSize);               
                if (newProgress != progress)
                 progress = informProgress(fileSize, newProgress, dirName, fileName, callbackId);

            }

            fos.close();

            Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "Download finished");

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("status", 1);
            obj.put("total", fileSize);
            obj.put("file", fileName);
            obj.put("dir", dirName);
            obj.put("progress", progress);

            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "File Not Found: " + e);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, 404);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("PhoneGapLog", "Error: " + e);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private int informProgress(int fileSize, int progress, String dirName, String fileName, String callbackId) throws InterruptedException, JSONException {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("status", 0);
        obj.put("total", fileSize);
        obj.put("file", fileName);
        obj.put("dir", dirName);
        obj.put("progress", progress);

        PluginResult res = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj);
        res.setKeepCallback(true);
        success(res, callbackId);

        //Give a chance for the progress to be sent to javascript
        Thread.sleep(100);

        return progress; 
    }

}
```

Comment: No. I am using phonegap

Comment: Did you try cleaning it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for your java build path for the correct Lib for Phonegap

Comment: @Pyare Can't be *too* fine, or it'd work: `com.phonegap.plugins.downloader.MainActivity` or one of its dependencies isn't found.

Comment: let me check once @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, add  cordova-XXX.jar to java build path and remember to check the box next to cordova-XXX.jar in the "Order and Export" tab.